# Difference Between Two Lists with Duplicates in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists that contain many of the same items, including duplicate items. I want to check which items in the first list are not in the second list. For example, I might have one list like this:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
```

and one list like this:

```
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
```

Comparing these two lists I would want to return a third list like this:

```
l3 = ['c']
```

I am currently using some terrible code that I made a while ago that I'm fairly certain doesn't even work properly shown below.

```
def list_difference(l1,l2):
    for i in range(0, len(l1)):
        for j in range(0, len(l2)):
            if l1[i] == l1[j]:
                l1[i] = 'damn'
                l2[j] = 'damn'
    l3 = []
    for item in l1:
        if item!='damn':
            l3.append(item)
    return l3
```

How can I better accomplish this task?

Comment: Why `l3 = ['c']`? letter c is in both `l1` and `l2` I don't understand

Comment: Does the order matter? I.e. would `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,2,4,3]` end with a `[3,4]` or `[4,3]`? Or do you just want to check that if `l1` contains `X` n-times, then `l2` should contain `X` n-times too (and vice-versa)?

Comment: Well, it should work but it's destructive and O(n^2 + n).

Comment: Please define "difference" more clearly. What problem are you trying to solve by getting the difference of the two lists?

Comment: @CésarBustíos: there are two `'c'` in `l1` and only one `'c'` in `l2` so the difference is `["c"]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070643/subtracting-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You didn't specify if the order matters. If it does not, you can do this in >= Python 2.7:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(l1)
c2 = Counter(l2)

diff = c1-c2
print list(diff.elements())
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use sets (http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html)

Comment: @rotoglup Sets won't work; there are duplicate elements that would disappear, and sets don't retain order.

Comment: @aaron Sure, but it seems that I don't really understand the question/problem then, anyway... :P

Comment: here's [solution that preserves order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14733043/4279).

Answer (score 9):

Create [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s for both lists, then `subtract` one from the other.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,1,2]
b = [1,2,3,1]

c = Counter(a)
c.subtract(Counter(b))
```

Comment: you could call: `c.subtract(b)` (omit Counter). Add `print list(c.elements())` for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

To take into account both duplicates and the order of elements:

```
from collections import Counter

def list_difference(a, b):
    count = Counter(a) # count items in a
    count.subtract(b)  # subtract items that are in b
    diff = []
    for x in a:
        if count[x] > 0:
           count[x] -= 1
           diff.append(x)
    return diff
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/ObaSqC)

```
print(list_difference("z y z x v x y x u".split(), "x y z w z".split()))
# -> ['y', 'x', 'v', 'x', 'u']
```

Python 2.5 version:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def list_difference25(a, b):
    # count items in a
    count = defaultdict(int) # item -> number of occurrences
    for x in a:
        count[x] += 1

    # subtract items that are in b
    for x in b: 
        count[x] -= 1

    diff = []
    for x in a:
        if count[x] > 0:
           count[x] -= 1
           diff.append(x)
    return diff
```

Answer (score 5):

Counters are new in Python 2.7.
For a general solution to substract a from b:

```
def list_difference(b, a):
    c = list(b)
    for item in a:
       try:
           c.remove(item)
       except ValueError:
           pass            #or maybe you want to keep a values here
    return c
```

Comment: By itself, this doesn't work - it throws `ValueError` for items in a not in b.

Comment: +1 for paying attention to Python versions- this is the answer

Comment: `c.remove(item)` is `O(n)` operation making the algorithm `O(n**2)` that might be slow for large `b`.

Comment: yes. your code for `list_difference25` is already twice as faster only with len(b) = 17. Impressive...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

`list(filter(lambda x:l1.remove(x),li2))
print(l1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Sequence

def duplicates_difference(a: Sequence, b: Sequence) -> Counter:
    """
    >>> duplicates_difference([1,2],[1,2,2,3])
    Counter({2: 1, 3: 1})
    """
    shorter, longer = sorted([a, b], key=len)
    return Counter(longer) - Counter(shorter)
```