# Create a complement of list preserving duplicate values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given list `a  = [1, 2, 2, 3]` and its sublist `b = [1, 2]` find a list complementing b in such a way that `sorted(a) == sorted(b + complement)`. In the example above the `complement` would be a list of `[2, 3]`.

It is tempting to use list comprehension:

```
complement = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

or sets:

```
complement = list(set(a) - set(b))
```

However, both of this ways will return `complement = [3]`.

An obvious way of doing it would be:

```
complement = a[:]
for element in b:
    complement.remove(element)
```

But that feels deeply unsatisfying and not very *Pythonic*. Am I missing an obvious idiom or is this the way?

As pointed out below what about performance this is `O(n^2)` Is there more efficient way?

Comment: you can create a list comprehension from the *unsatisfying option. Would that make it *satisfying?

Comment: Don't see how just post it !

Comment: I do not really see what is that much *un-Pythonic* about it. It is not *completely* declarative, but still very readable. I would be more concerned with performance, since this will run in *O(n^2)*, which is not very nice...

Comment: @JanHak just replace the last two lines with an unassigned `[complement.remove(element) for element in b]` but as @Willem says, it is not about the looks. This is almost a *hack of the list comprehension since we are not creating a list but simply using the syntax to do something else

Comment: @JanHak Will `b` always contain the first *n* elements of `a`?

Comment: @Ev. Kounis that will return a list of two None values ;) but I guess the side effect is that the original complement will change. No `b` can be any subset.

Comment: @JanHak I said *unassigned*. do not assign it to `complement`. Just type it as it is and do `print(complement)` on the next line.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106227/difference-between-two-lists-with-duplicates-in-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only more *declarative* and thus *Pythonic* way that pops into my mind and that **improves performance** for large `b` (and `a`) is to use some sort of counter with decrement:

```
from collections import Counter

class DecrementCounter(Counter):

    def decrement(self,x):
        if self[x]:
            self[x] -= 1
            return True
        return False
```

Now we can use list comprehension:

```
b_count = DecrementCounter(b)
complement = [x for x in a if not b_count.decrement(x)]
```

Here we thus keep track of the counts in `b`, for each element in `a` we look whether it is part of `b_count`. If that is indeed the case we decrement the counter and ignore the element. Otherwise we add it to the `complement`. Note that this only works, if we are sure **such `complement` exists**.

**After** you have constructed the `complement`, you can check if the complement exists with:

```
not bool(+b_count)
```

If this is `False`, then **such complement cannot be constructed** (for instance `a=[1]` and `b=[1,3]`). So a full implementation could be:

```
b_count = DecrementCounter(b)
complement = [x for x in a if not b_count.decrement(x)]
if +b_count:
    raise ValueError('complement cannot be constructed')
```

If dictionary lookup runs in *O(1)* (which it usually does, only in rare occasions it is *O(n)*), then this algorithm runs in *O(|a|+|b|)* (so the sum of the sizes of the lists). Whereas the `remove` approach will usually run in *O(|a|×|b|)*.

Comment: Thanks @Willem great answer learned something! I had to wrap my head around the side-effect of calling the method decrement - creative!

Comment: @Hironsan: That's why (it is even in boldface), the answer says: "*such complement exists.*". If you swap `a` and `b`, such complement does not exists.

Comment: @Hironsan: I included a test which will raise a `ValueError` in case no such complement can be constructed.

Comment: ... why `bool(+b_count)`? Isn't that equivalent to simply `b_count` in the boolean context? AFAIK `+counter == counter` if `isinstance(counter, Counter)`, so the `+` does literally nothing, except causing confusion, and bool again... it's what python does anyway when checking the truthiness of a value.

Comment: For a counter, the `+` removes the negative and zero Countdown. The `bool` can indeed be omitted.

Comment: The truthness of the counter is inherited from the underlying dictionary. The + on the other hand is counter specific. Its usage is not tot spread confusion.

Answer (score 5):

In order to reduce complexity to your already valid approach, you could use `collections.Counter` (which is a specialized dictionary with fast lookup) to count items in both lists.

Then update the count by substracting values, and in the end filter the list by only keeping items whose count is > 0 and rebuild it/chain it using `itertools.chain`

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

a  = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2]

print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x*[k] for k,x in (Counter(a)-Counter(b)).items() if x > 0)))
```

result:

```
[2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: what is `Counter` order ? is it _O(n)_?

Comment: But won't this result in the fact that if `complement` should have two twos, it will only have one? like `a=[1,2,2,2]`, `b=[1,2]`... Here the condition is that if `x > 0`, you only emit it once.

Comment: Counter is a dictionary: lookup is less that `O(n)`

Comment: counting element in a list is less than _O(n)_ using Counter?!

Comment: not counting, lookup. You have to analyse the data, for that you have to run through it once. But after that, lookup is fast.

Answer (score 2):

O(n log n)

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2]
a.sort()
b.sort()

L = []
i = j = 0
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] < b[j]:
        L.append(a[i])
        i += 1
    elif a[i] > b[j]:
        L.append(b[j])
        j += 1
    else:
        i += 1
        j += 1

while i < len(a):
    L.append(a[i])
    i += 1

while j < len(b):
    L.append(b[j])
    j += 1

print(L)
```

Comment: If I swap `a` and `b`, it has no effect :)

Answer (score 2):

If the order of elements in the complement doesn't matter, then collections.Counter is all that is needed:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 2]
b = [1, 2]

complement = list((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements())  # complement = [2, 3]
```

If the order of items in the complement should be the same order as in the original list, then use something like this:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import count

a = [1,2,3,2]
b = [2,1]

c = Counter(b)
d = defaultdict(count)

complement = [x for x in a if next(d[x]) >= c[x]]  # complement = [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Main idea: if the values are not unique, make them unique

```
def add_duplicate_position(items):
    element_counter = {}
    for item in items:
        element_counter[item] = element_counter.setdefault(item,-1) + 1
        yield element_counter[item], item
    
assert list(add_duplicate_position([1, 2, 2, 3])) == [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 3)]

def create_complementary_list_with_duplicates(a,b):
    a = list(add_duplicate_position(a))
    b = set(add_duplicate_position(b))
    return [item for _,item in [x for x in a if x not in b]]
  
a = [1, 2, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2]
assert create_complementary_list_with_duplicates(a,b) == [2, 3]
```