# Remove elements from list that is in another list while keeping duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to remove elements in l1 that are in l2 while keeping duplicates.

Input:

```
l1 = [a, b, b, a, c, c, a]
l2 = [c, b]
```

Output:

```
l3 = [a, b, a, c, a]
```

I have tried to find a good answer for this, but all I seem to find is ways of doing this which also deletes the duplicates. First I tried doing this with set() until I realised it removes duplicates, then I tried using numpy and setdiff1d but couldn't get that to work. Using list comprehension like

```
[item for item in x if item not in y]
```

also removed duplicates. What is the simplest way of removing elements from a list that are in an other list while not removing duplicates? Order of the lists is not important.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your list `l2` won't have duplicates? What is the expected output it l2 is, for example, `[c, b, b]`?

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want to remove the first occurence of each value of `l2`, or all of them, but keeping one if they appear in a group of 2? And in this case, what if there are 3 in  a row?

Comment: Also: [Difference Between Two Lists with Duplicates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8106227/7851470)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a little bit more complex loops:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a']
l2 = ['c', 'b']
l3=[]
for item in l1:
    if item in l2:
        l2.remove(item)
    else:
        l3.append(item)
>>>l3
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: Upvote but the time complexity of both `remove` and `in` operator in `list` are `O(n)`.So it might have a poor performance when there comes some large data.

Answer (score 8):

Just use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ["a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a"]
l2 = ["c", "b"]

print(list((Counter(l1)-Counter(l2)).elements()))
```

And result:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: "Order of the lists is not important."

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and shortest way:

```
l3 = l1.copy()
for x in l2:
    l3.remove(x)
```

1. You make a copy of the list that you want to pop the elements
2. For each element in the second list you try to remove it in the first one

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects.

Comment: Nice thinking, it is not advised to use list comprehension without assignment, try changing it to imperative way with `:`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def remove_dup(l1,l2):
  d={}
  l3=[]
  for i in l1:
    if i not in d:
      d[i]=1
    else:
      d[i]+=1
  for i in l2:
    if i in d:
      d[i]-=1

  for i in d:
    for count in range(d[i]):
      l3.append(i)

  return l3




l1 = ["a", "b", "b", "a", "c","c", "a"]
l2 = ["c", "b"]
print(remove_dup(l1,l2))
'''


You can use a dict to store the count for the elements in the first loop , then iterate through the second one reducing the count and then finally append it in l3 ,
```