# Mastermind Game How to not add number if previously has been added

Tags: python

```
import random

def compare(player_colors, computer_colors):
    both_correct = 0
    correct_color_only = 0

    if player_colors[0] == computer_colors[0]:
        both_correct += 1

    if player_colors[1] == computer_colors[1]:
        both_correct += 1
    
    if player_colors[2] == computer_colors[2]:
        both_correct += 1
 
    if player_colors[3] == computer_colors[3]:
        both_correct += 1
    
    for player in player_colors:
        if player in computer_colors:
            correct_color_only += 1



    if both_correct == 4:
        return f"Congratulations!!! You've guessed the correct answer. {player_colors}"

    print(f"Correct Colours: {correct_color_only}")
    print(f"Correct Colours and Positions: {both_correct}")


colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "white", "orange"]
computer_colors = []
player_colors = []

for _ in range(4):
    computer_color = random.choice(colors)
    computer_colors.append(computer_color[0])

print("Welcome to Mastermind.")


game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    print(colors)
    print(computer_colors)
    print("Choose 4 colours from above. Just write the first letter of your color will do.")
    player_answer1 = input("First color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer1)
    player_answer2 = input("Second color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer2)
    player_answer3 = input("Third color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer3)
    player_answer4 = input("Fourth color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer4)
    answee = compare(player_colors, computer_colors)
    print(answee)
```

Hello guys, basically i was trying to do a mastermind game. The error for this programme is the correct colour. For example, if there are 3 red in the answer and the player guesses 4 red, it will count as 4 correct answer. How can I solve this issues. Thank you.

Edit version

```
import random

def compare(player_colors, computer_colors):
    both_correct = 0
    correct_color_only = 4
    correct_answer = 0
    attempts = 10

    if player_colors[0] == computer_colors[0]:
        both_correct += 1

    if player_colors[1] == computer_colors[1]:
        both_correct += 1

    if player_colors[2] == computer_colors[2]:
        both_correct += 1

    if player_colors[3] == computer_colors[3]:
        both_correct += 1

    li_dif = [i for i in player_colors + computer_colors if i not in player_colors or i not in computer_colors]
    correct_answer = correct_color_only - len(li_dif)

    if both_correct == 4:
        return f"Congratulations!!! You've guessed the correct answer. {player_colors}"

    print(f"Correct Colours: {correct_answer}")
    print(f"Correct Colours and Positions: {both_correct}")
    new_attempts = attempts - 1
    print(f"You have {new_attempts} attempts left. ")






colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "white", "orange"]
computer_colors = []
player_colors = []

for _ in range(4):
    computer_color = random.choice(colors)
    computer_colors.append(computer_color[0])

print("Welcome to Mastermind.")


game_is_on = True


while game_is_on:
    print(colors)
    print(computer_colors)
    print("Choose 4 colours from above. Just write the first letter of your color will do.")
    player_answer1 = input("First color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer1)
    player_answer2 = input("Second color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer2)
    player_answer3 = input("Third color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer3)
    player_answer4 = input("Fourth color: ").lower()
    player_colors.append(player_answer4)
    answee = compare(player_colors, computer_colors)
    print(answee)
```

Basically I add your code and it works but then the problem is I mentioned just now.

Comment: hey, I am unable to recreate the error, please provide more information on what exactly is wrong and what are the exact inputs when the error occurs.

Comment: You might try counting how many of each color the player has guessed, then doing math on the counts rather than the positions

Comment: The problem is I want to count the correct colour only. However, if I use the for loops like above it will continue adding the correct colour value if I guess the second time. @Geom

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the second 'in' operator here:

```
for player in player_colors:
    if player in computer_colors:
        correct_color_only += 1
```

`if player in computer_colors` will find the first occurrence of `player` in `computer_colors`. This means that your if statement will work correctly if all `computer_colors` values are unique but will cause issues if there are repeating `colours` in `computer_colors`.

---

you can  get the difference between two lists like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106227/difference-between-two-lists-with-duplicates-in-python):

```
l1 = ['r', 'r', 'r', 'b']
l2 = ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r']

from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(l1)
c2 = Counter(l2)

diff = c1-c2
print(list(diff.elements()))
```

---

### Edit:

```
# Option 1
# difference of two lists using set()

l1 = ['r', 'r', 'r', 'b']
l2 = ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r']

def diffSet(l1, l2):
    return list(set(l1) - set(l2)) + list(set(l2) - set(l1))
 
print(diffSet(l1, l2))

# OPTION 2
#Difference of two lists list comprehension

def diff(l1, l2):
    li_dif = [i for i in l1 + l2 if i not in l1 or i not in l2]
    return li_dif

print(diff(l1, l2))
```

Comment: Hi, is there any other ways to do it without importing any libraries?

Comment: li_dif = [i for i in player_colors + computer_colors if i not in player_colors or i not in computer_colors]
    correct_answer = correct_color_only - len(li_dif)

Comment: Hi, the options yes it works but then the problem here is whenever im guessing the second time it will increase from previous number too. Example computer colours are 4x red and I guess 3 red, the second time im guessing red again it will have 4 correct colours.

Comment: Can this be because the "player_colors = []" is outside the while loop? You just keep appending to it but you never clean it and you always check for the first four items inside it.

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry for not knowing how to do this. I just edited my post with the version I'm currently having.