# Python difference between two lists with possibly repeating values

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, each with non-unique numbers, meaning they can have the same value multiple times.

I need to find the difference between the two, accounting for the fact that the same values may appear multiple times (so I can't take the difference between the set of each). So, I need to check if a value occurs more times in the first list than the second.

The lists are:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 2]
l2 = [1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 8, 9]

# Sorted and justified
l1 = [1,    2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
l2 = [1, 1, 2,    3,    4,    8, 9]
```

The list elements can be string or int or float.
So the result lists should be:

```
difference(l1, l2) == [3, 5, 2] 
# There is an extra 2 and 3 in l1 that is not in l2, and a 5 in l1 but not l2. 

difference(l2, l1) == [1]
# The extra 1 is the only value in l2 but not in l1.
```

I have tried list comprehension `[x for x in l1 if x not in l2]` which does not work, as it does not account for the repeated values in both.

Comment: I have tried list generator, only thing I could think of for this case without building a looping function [x for x in l1 if x not in l2 ] does not work

Comment: Are the values going to be integers, or do you need a more generic solution?

Comment: How is this possibly downvoted already with no explanation.  Jeez...

Comment: Good question.  More generic, can be strings as well...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070643/subtracting-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order is *not* important, you could use a `Counter` (see the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module of the standard library):

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = [1,2,5,3,3,4,9,8,2]
l2 = [1,1,3,2,4,8,9]

c1 = Counter(l1) # Counter({2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1, 5: 1, 4: 1, 9: 1, 8: 1})
c2 = Counter(l2) # Counter({1: 2, 3: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1})

diff1 = list((c1-c2).keys()) # [2, 5, 3]
diff2 = list((c2-c1).keys()) # [1]
```

This is fairly general and works with strings, too:

```
...
l1 = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar']
l2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz']
...
# diff1 == ['foo']
# diff2 == ['bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that many people will come here for multiset differences (e.g.: `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3] - [1, 2, 2] == [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]`), so I'll post that answer here too:

```
import collections

def multiset_difference(a, b):
    """Compute a - b of two multisets a and b"""
    a = collections.Counter(a)
    b = collections.Counter(b)

    difference = a - b
    return difference  # Remove this line if you want it as a list

    as_list = []
    for item, count in difference.items():
        as_list.extend([item] * count)
    return as_list

def ordered_multiset_difference(a, b):
    """As above, but preserves order and is O(ab) worst case"""
    difference = list(a)
    depleted = set()  # Values that aren't in difference to prevent searching the list again
    for i in b:
        if i not in depleted:
            try:
                difference.remove(i)
            except ValueError:
                depleted.add(i)
    return difference
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter` is probably a better choice, but to roll it yourself:

```
def diff(a, b):
    result = []
    cpy = b[:]
    for ele in a:
        if ele in cpy:
            cpy.remove(ele)
        else:
            result.append(ele)
    return result
```

or as an abusive one-liner:

```
def diff(a, b):
    return [ele for ele in a if ele not in b or b.remove(ele)]
```

The one liner destroys `b` in the process of building the difference, so you may want to pass it a copy: `diff(l1, l2[:])`, or use:

```
def diff(a, b):
    cpy = b[:]
    return [ele for ele in a if ele not in cpy or cpy.remove(ele)]
```

Comment: `if ele in cpy: cpy.remove(ele)` scans through the list twice. The one-liner doesn't handle falsey values properly (e.g., `diff([0, 0, 1], [1])` -> `[]`). If you want a one-liner so badly, just use the list comprehension to not include it. `[ele for ele in a if ele in cpy or cpy.remove(ele)]`. But this, again, goes over the list twice every time it needs to remove.

Comment: @Artyer I've fixed the filter... I'm curious if you've tried your list comprehension change, as it yields a `ValueError` for me. And, as I mentioned, Counter is probably a better option.

Comment: Oops. I meant forgot a `not`. `[ele for ele in a if ele not in cpy or cpy.remove(ele)]`

Comment: @Artyer I figured out what you meant and fixed it. That is much nicer looking :)